# Anybody knows how ->dump() works?

Tags: php, phalcon

Anybody knows how `$myModelClass->dump()` works?

I tried several times with models in different states but switched to

```
var_dump($myModelClass->toArray());
```

because `->dump()` doesn't output (or return) anything for me.

Edit:
And `var_dump($myModelClass->dump());` dumps always an empty array.

Edit2:
Here' an example how I use it in the indexAction of IndexController:

```
public function indexAction() {
   $this->view->disable();
   $u = new User();
   $u = $u::findFirstByUsersId(56);
   var_dump($u->dump()); //empty array
   $u = new User();
   $u = $u->find('usersId = '.(56))->getFirst();
   var_dump($u->dump()); //empty array
   var_dump($u->toArray()); //correct output
}
```

Hierarchy for User is:

```
User <- BaseUser <- UsersStorage <- Phalcon\Mvc\Model
```

Which should not matter, because the above example gives same results with UsersStorage objects.

Answer (score 1):

Per the PhalconPHP API, ->dump() must be used in conjunction with var_dump().

```
$myModelClass = SomeClass::find();

foreach ($myModelClass as $record) {
    var_dump($record->dump());
    exit;
}
```

or

```
$myModelClass = SomeClass::findFirst(1);
var_dump($myModelClass->dump());
exit;
```

http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Model.html

Comment: Unfortunately this also results in a dump of an empty array.

Comment: Could you post your full code? I tried it and it works. The only difference between toArray() and dump() is with dump() you get all of the object properties that aren't actually mapped to a db field. Also, dump() doesn't appear to work directly with find(). It only works with findFirst() and if you do a foreach on a find() result set you can call dump() on each of those. Be certain also that you call exit() after your var_dump as Phalcon won't allow output if a view is allowed to be rendered. Perhaps it was working and the blank screen was a false empty array.